# Angular Material table has no design

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material

Why is my Angular material table has no design? It is not the same as the tables I've seen on the documentation. Here is the code:

```
<mat-table>
  <ng-container matColumnDef="userId">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>User ID</mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">{{row.userId}}</mat-cell>
  </ng-container>
  <ng-container matColumnDef="id">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>ID</mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">{{row.id}}</mat-cell>
  </ng-container>
  <ng-container matColumnDef="title">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Title</mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">{{row.title}}</mat-cell>
  </ng-container>
  <ng-container matColumnDef="completed">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Completed</mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">{{row.completed}}</mat-cell>
  </ng-container>
  <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
  <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns"></mat-row>
</mat-table>
<mat-paginator [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 25, 100]"></mat-paginator>
```

Here is the output table
[image: Here is the output table]

Comment: Edit: I already solved it. I forgot to import the prebuilt theme in my style.scss

Comment: Have you added any the styling of material design? That could be the solution if you have not

Comment: It already worked!
I forgot to put this in my style.scss:
@import "~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/deeppurple-amber.css";

Comment: okay, yeah that's what i was saying. Good yo figured yourself as well

Answer (score 1):

by default it is plain table with white colour and black colour if used different theme of the angular material. If you want to style it. You can style it using simple css by adding the color in the css as

```css
tr{
  background-color:green;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this.

app.component.html

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8">

  <!--- Note that these columns can be defined in any order.
        The actual rendered columns are set as a property on the row definition" -->

  <!-- Position Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="position">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> No. </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.position}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <!-- Name Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Name </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.name}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <!-- Weight Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="weight">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Weight </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.weight}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <!-- Symbol Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="symbol">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Symbol </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.symbol}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
</table>
```

app.component.ts
add this

```
export interface PeriodicElement {
    name: string;
    position: number;
    weight: number;
    symbol: string;
}

const ELEMENT_DATA: PeriodicElement[] = [
    {position: 1, name: 'Hydrogen', weight: 1.0079, symbol: 'H'},
    {position: 2, name: 'Helium', weight: 4.0026, symbol: 'He'},
    {position: 3, name: 'Lithium', weight: 6.941, symbol: 'Li'},
    {position: 4, name: 'Beryllium', weight: 9.0122, symbol: 'Be'},
    {position: 5, name: 'Boron', weight: 10.811, symbol: 'B'},
    {position: 6, name: 'Carbon', weight: 12.0107, symbol: 'C'},
    {position: 7, name: 'Nitrogen', weight: 14.0067, symbol: 'N'},
    {position: 8, name: 'Oxygen', weight: 15.9994, symbol: 'O'},
    {position: 9, name: 'Fluorine', weight: 18.9984, symbol: 'F'},
    {position: 10, name: 'Neon', weight: 20.1797, symbol: 'Ne'},
];
```

then add these two variable

```
displayedColumns: string[] = ['position', 'name', 'weight', 'symbol'];
dataSource = ELEMENT_DATA;
```

then in css

```
table {
  width: 100%;
}
```

you can check [working demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-table-examples)

Let me know if you still have doubts.